# exec vs execFile nodeJs

Tags: node.js, child-process

I want to run a command in command-prompt using nodejs.
Based on https://dzone.com/articles/understanding-execfile-spawn-exec-and-fork-in-node, i used

```
child_process.execFile('protractor', ['./src/convertedJs/tempProtractorconfig.js'], (err, stdout, stderr) => {}
```

The above code throws a ENOENT error.
But when i run

```
child_process.exec('protractor ./src/convertedJs/tempProtractorconfig.js', (err,stdout,stderr) => {}`
```

everything works fine.
Can somebody explain what is happening?

Comment: Are you sure you are running both of them from the same directory?

Comment: yepss..i am running in the same dir

Answer (score 14):

There is a difference between using child_process.exec() and child_process.execFile() in that the latter won't spawn a shell whereas the former will.

Nodejs [documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_spawning_bat_and_cmd_files_on_windows) states:

> On Windows, however, .bat and .cmd files are not executable on their own without a terminal, and therefore cannot be launched using child_process.execFile(). When running on Windows, .bat and .cmd files can be invoked using child_process.spawn() with the shell option set, with child_process.exec(), or by spawning cmd.exe and passing the .bat or .cmd file as an argument (which is what the shell option and child_process.exec() do).

I could launch them... though not without problem.

My observations:

- Running the following `child_process.execFile('ls', ...)` works on Linux whereas `child_process.execFile('dir', ...)` doesn't work on Windows.
- specifying the fullpath to the protractor executable on Windows, e.g. `child_process.execFile('C:\\Users\\Jperl\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\protractor.cmd', ...)` works as expected! **No shell means we don't have access to the path variable**.

Don't use execFile for Windows at all. Instead use either `spawn` or `exec`:

```
var protractor = child_process.spawn('protractor', ['./src/convertedJs/tempProtractorconfig.js'], {shell: true});
```

or

```
var protractor = child_process.spawn('cmd', ['/c', 'protractor', './src/convertedJs/tempProtractorconfig.js']);
```

Comment: Is this still correct? Looking at the Node.js documentation I see explicit mention of how to use this function on Windows - https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_processexecfilefile-args-options-callback

Comment: @ZachSmith I think so, all the things I said are still there https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#spawning-bat-and-cmd-files-on-windows The second part is based on my own observations back then.

Comment: Should still be correct. It's quite easy to test, though.

Comment: Is `exec(` the same as `execFile` with `shell` option set to `true` ?

Answer (score 2):

in nodejs v9.5.0, the `exec`  is defined as below in file lib/child_process.js

```
exports.exec = function(command /*, options, callback*/) {
    var opts = normalizeExecArgs.apply(null, arguments);
    return exports.execFile(opts.file, opts.options, opts.callback);
};
```

that means ,finally `exec` call `execFile` to excute your command , so in your case it quite strange that `execFile` fail but `exec` is not

Answer (score 0):

I also faced some issue to start a node process by using "node myfile.js",but when I added the location of the node.exe like 'path of node.exe/node.exe myfile.js ' it was working fine like I expected

Comment: I forgot to add onething,maybe try adding the file path of protractor will help you.